# Using C# how can I return the value of a toggle Switch from xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.android, toggle

I have two xaml toggles in separate files that I want to update simultaneously (if one is switched on the other should be too (and vice versa). My first switch in xaml is:

`<Switch Grid.Column="1" x:Name="toggleSwitch1" IsToggled="true" Toggled="OnToggled"/>`
with the method

```
 void OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        //updateConsentValueForCategory();
        if (toggleSwitch1.IsToggled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Toggled on");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Toggled off");
        }
    }
```

Converting OnToggled() to a return type gives me an error for toggleSwitch1 saying an object reference is required because it is non-static.
How can I pull the toggle value and update another xaml file in sync?

Comment: between your question, what you show its not clear

Comment: the method I have shown is just the associated C# for a toggle. I'm looking for a method to use with a toggle that will return its status, and maybe even another method that will get it and update a different xaml toggle

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you want, the Ontoggled is an event, you cant return value from an event

Comment: Yeah that's my problem. So how would I write a method that returns the value from the provided xaml element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using C# how can I return the value of a toggle Switch from xaml

You can use several methods to achieve this .

1.use event `Toggled` of `Switch`  as you mentioned.

You can refer to the following code:

```
private void OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    Switch mySwitch1 = (Switch)sender;
    if (mySwitch1.IsToggled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Toggled on" );
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Toggled off");
    }
}
```

2.Another method is to use the binding way.

Just create a ViewModel for the current page(e.g.`TestPage1`)  and create a field (e.g. `SwithOne`) for property `IsToggled` of Switch .

Please refer to the following code :

Create a `ViewModel` class(e.g. `MyViewModel.cs`) and create field `SwithOne` .Make the ViewModel implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
 public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool swithOne;
    public bool SwithOne
    {
        set
        {
            if (swithOne != value)
            {
                swithOne = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SwithOne");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return swithOne;
        }
    }


    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SwithOne = true; // assign a value for `SwithOne `
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

**TestPage1.xaml.cs.**

```
public partial class TestPage1 : ContentPage
{
     MyViewModel myViewModel;

    public TestPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = myViewModel;
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync( new TestPage2(myViewModel.SwithOne));
    }

}
```

**TestPage1.xaml**

```
        <Switch x:Name="toggleSwitch1" IsToggled="{Binding SwithOne}"   HorizontalOptions="Center">
        </Switch>
        <Button  Text="navigate"  Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

Comment: Hey there, I got no errors but this didn't sync my toggles. My response was a little too long for this comment so I've made a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027409/how-to-bind-two-switch-controls-in-separate-classes-to-the-same-bool-property). I would really appreciate it if you could take a look!

Comment: I just answered problem `how can I return the value of a toggle Switch from xaml` .If you want to sync  toggles in different pages, I will give an answer in the new question  you posted.

Comment: One problem, one thread. If my answer is useful for this problem `Using C# how can I return the value of a toggle Switch from xaml`, could you please mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

the sender object contains the source of event, here the Switch

```
 void OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        //updateConsentValueForCategory();
        var switch = (Switch)sender;
        if (switch.IsToggled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Toggled on");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Toggled off");
        }
    }
```