# How to bind two Switch controls in separate classes to the same bool property?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, toggle

I am making a preference center that needs to sync updates for two separate Switch toggles with the same boolean/ toggle value. I am using Xamarin Forms with C#. I have a **ViewModel.cs** file such as

```
namespace XamarinDemoApp
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool swithOne;
    public bool SwithOne
    {
        set
        {
            if (swithOne != value)
            {
                swithOne = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SwithOne");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return swithOne;
        }
    }

public MyViewModel()
    {
        SwithOne = true; // assign a value for `SwithOne `
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
}
```

Then my **AllowSaleToggleTab.xaml.cs** looks like

```
namespace XamarinDemoApp
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AllowSaleToggleTab : ContentPage
{
    MyViewModel myViewModel;
    public AllowSaleToggleTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = myViewModel;
    }
}
}
```

The other toggle tab is **PC.xaml.cs**

```
namespace XamarinDemoApp
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

public partial class PC : ContentPage
{
    MyViewModel myViewModel;

    public PC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine("PC Initialized");
        myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = myViewModel;
    }
}
}
```

Finally, both my accompanying **PC.xaml** and **AllowSaleToggleTab.xaml** files have the elements

```html
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:xamarindemoapp="clr-namespace:XamarinDemoApp" x:DataType="xamarindemoapp:MyViewModel"
             x:Class="XamarinDemoApp.AllowSaleToggleTab">
    <Switch x:Name="ToggleSwitch1"  IsToggled="{Binding SwithOne}"/>
```

Yet they still don't sync. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: each page has it's own instance of the VM.  Multiple instances of the same class are entirely independent of each other

Comment: You create different instances of your ViewModel, each one for each page. It should be single for both pages. Like in my previous answer for WPF, where I create instance in one Window, then pass is as argument to other two, so they use same ViewModel (here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934877/how-can-i-write-a-method-that-returns-the-value-of-a-of-xaml-toggle-switch/69952912#69952912)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, however I have a MainActivity.cs within my XamarinDemoApp.android package and an App.xaml.cs file in my XamarinDemoApp package. Where should I make the parent instance?

Comment: if both pages are in the Forms project, put it there.  You could also use a singleton pattern, or make a static class, etc.  There are many ways you could solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your code is used，but there are several methods to achieve this.

For example,you can pass the data between two different Pages when navigating or use [Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send the data message between the two pages.

You can refer to  the following code(I combined the two methods above):

**TestPage1.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Switch x:Name="toggleSwitch1" IsToggled="{Binding SwithOne}"   HorizontalOptions="Center">
        </Switch>
        <Button  Text="navigate to Page2"  Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**TestPage1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage1 : ContentPage
{
     MyViewModel myViewModel;
    public TestPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = myViewModel;
    }
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync( new TestPage2(myViewModel.SwithOne));//myViewModel.SwithOne
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public  class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    private  bool _swithOne { get; set; }
    public  bool SwithOne
    {
        set
        {
            if (_swithOne != value)
            {
                _swithOne = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SwithOne");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _swithOne;
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SwithOne = true;

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, object>(this, "PassDataToOne", (sender, args) =>
        {
            bool value = (bool)args;

            if (value!= SwithOne) {

                SwithOne = value;
            }
          
        });
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected   void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

**TestPage2.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Switch x:Name="toggleSwitch2" IsToggled="{Binding SwithTwo}"   HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button  Text="Navigate To  Page 1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**TestPage2.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage2 : ContentPage
{
    MyViewModel2 myViewModel;

    public TestPage2(bool isToggled)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

         myViewModel = new MyViewModel2(isToggled);

        BindingContext = myViewModel;
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel2.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel2: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _swithTwo;
    public bool SwithTwo
    {
        set
        {
            if (_swithTwo != value)
            {
                _swithTwo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SwithTwo");

                MessagingCenter.Send<object, object>(this, "PassDataToOne", _swithTwo);

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _swithTwo;
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel2( bool isToggled)
    {
        SwithTwo = isToggled;
    }


    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Note:**

1.I Used two different ViewModels for the two pages(`TestPage1` and `TestPage2`), TestPage1's ViewModel is `MyViewModel`, and TestPage1's ViewModel is `MyViewModel2`.

2.After changing the status of `Switch` in `TestPage1`,we can pass the value `SwithOne` in `MyViewModel.cs` to `TestPage2` by the Constructor:

```
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync( new TestPage2(myViewModel.SwithOne));//myViewModel.SwithOne
    }
```

3.If we change the value of `SwithTwo` in `TestPage2`,we can use `MessagingCenter` to send the value to `TestPage1`:

```
   public class MyViewModel2: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _swithTwo;
    public bool SwithTwo
    {
        set
        {
            if (_swithTwo != value)
            {
                _swithTwo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SwithTwo");

                MessagingCenter.Send<object, object>(this, "PassDataToOne", _swithTwo);

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _swithTwo;
        }
    }
// other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way I know is to use a static object.

Variable Holder:

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public static SomeClass Instance {get;set;} = new SomeClass();

public string SharedString {get;set;}

#region The rest of property changed
...
#endregion
}
```

View 1

```
<Label Text={Binding Path=SharedString, Source={x:Static locationOfSomeClass:SomeClass.Instance}} />
```

View 2

```
<Label Text={Binding Path=SharedString, Source={x:Static locationOfSomeClass:SomeClass.Instance}} />
```

And whenever you change the string, like SomeClass.Instance.SharedString = "I'm updating this string"; you get an updated string in both locations. Make sure you have propertychanged.fody nuget installed.